# Im getting always a "#" in the end of my url when I click on my delete link to delete an user via jQuery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

Im have a list of users and When I click in my "delete" link Im removing my user via ajax.
And it is working fine but Im having a problem.

I have my users list in tihs directory: htttp://localhost/admin/dashboard.php?
nav=users/index

And When I click on delete link, and then I click "yes" on my dialog and my user is removed but I get a "#" in the end of my url, and I have some conflicts because of this.

Like this: htttp://localhost/admin/dashboard.php?
nav=users/index#

Do you see why this can be happening?

This is my jQuery:

```
$('.users').on('click','.j_userdelete',function(){
    var delid = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.users li[id="'+ delid +'"]').css('background','red');
    //when I click in my delete link I open my confirm dialog
    //my .confirm_dialog is only a background and .delete is div where I have yes and no buttons 
    $('.confirm_dialog').fadeIn("slow",function(){
        $('.delete').fadeIn("slow");
    });
    //If I click in my "no" link I close my dialog
    $("a#no").click(function(){
        $('.delete').fadeOut("slow",function(){
            $('.delete_dialog').fadeOut("slow"); 
        });
        $('.usuarios .users li[id="'+ delid +'"]').css('background','none');
    });

    //if I click in my "yes" link I have my post for delete
    $("a#yes").click(function(){

        $.post(url,{
            action:'users_del',
            idUser:delid
        },function(){
            window.setTimeout(function(){
                $('.users li[id="'+ delid +'"]').fadeOut("slow");
        },500);
        //and then I close my dialog
        $('.delete').fadeOut("fast",function(){
            $('.delete_dialog').fadeOut("fast"); 
        });
    });
});
return false;
})
```

Comment: There's no link here.

Comment: place `event.preventDefault()` before calling `ajax post`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, the default behavior of `a` tag is triggering a redirect. That's why you get redirect to your current url with a `#` suffix. To bypass this default behavior, place `event.preventDefault()` before calling `ajax post` as follow:

```
//if I click in my "yes" link I have my post for delete
$("a#yes").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.post(url,{
        action:'users_del',
        idUser:delid
    },function(){
        window.setTimeout(function(){
            $('.users li[id="'+ delid +'"]').fadeOut("slow");
    },500);
    //and then I close my dialog
    $('.delete').fadeOut("fast",function(){
        $('.delete_dialog').fadeOut("fast"); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want to do it from HTML itself.
simply put

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);"></a>
```

In this way you will not need any JavaScript fix for this.